# How can I group by this query that there's not two columns per entry

Tags: sql, sap-commerce-cloud

I have this query in flexible search:

```
SELECT
    {p.pk} AS PK,
    {year.code} AS year
FROM {Product AS p
    LEFT JOIN Year AS y ON {p.yearpk}={year.pk}
}
ORDER BY {p.pk} ASC
```

As result I get:

```
PK    |    year
---------------
1     |    null
1     |    2016
2     |    null
2     |    2016
```

How can I group by these multiple records into one like:

```
PK    |    year
---------------
1     |    2016
2     |    2016
```

I've already tried with "GROUP BY {p.pk}" but then the query doesn't returns me the result I've mentioned above - instead it returns 2 records but the year is null instead of 2016.

How can I solve this?

Comment: `SELECT {p.pk}, {year.code} FROM {Product as p},{Year as year} where {p.yearpk}={year.pk} ORDER BY {p.pk} ASC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `left join` to an `inner join`. That should solve your issue.